# Regular Expression to limit string length

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have an issue where I need to use a `RegularExpressionValidator` to limit the length of a string to 400 Characters.

My expression was `.{0,400}`

My question: Is there a way to limit the length of characters to 400 without taking into consideration blank spaces?

I want to be able to accept blank spaces in the string but not count it in the length.  Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't strictly possible with a regular expression but is in many languages. What language are you attempting to implement this in?

Comment: I am using the RegularExpressionValidator control in an asp.net web application (vb.net).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I pretty much agree with Greg, but here's the regex you want:

```
^\s*([^\s]\s*){0,400}$
```

@Boopid: If you really meant only the space character, replace \s with a space in the regex.

Comment: Shouldn't that be [^\s] instead of [^ ]? Other than that: nice!

Comment: (or does the questioner by 'blank spaces' really only mean the space character?)

Comment: Or simply \S instead of [^\s]

Comment: @Peter, ah yes, that is obviously nicer.

Comment: And if only regular spaces are to be checked for then "^ ([^ ] ){0,400}$" is the expression (without quotes)

Comment: @Peter: You need some asterisks in there, or it will only match space-character-space-character-space-character-space...

Comment: RicheiHindle - ooops, yes there should be a pair of asterisks there. Not sure how I missed those. :$

Comment: I agree that Greg's solution would be the best, but this helped in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you might want to write your own validator class instead of using the RegularExpressionValidator. Regular expressions certainly have their uses, but this doesn't sound like one of them.

Your custom validator could remove all the spaces, then check the length of the string. Ultimately, the code will be more readable than a regular expression that does the same thing.

Comment: I agree, just remove all whitespace and check the string's length.  Probably very efficient compared to the regex suggested above (although this is just a theory).